# Weird Safari animation rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

*takes deep breath*

Ok, I have a large div that acts as a background layer.  This div pans from left to right based on the link you select in a typical horizontal navigation.  It's a bit of a novelty thing.

The HTML structure:

```
<div id="scroll">
        <div class="container_16">
            <div id="header" class="grid_9 suffix_3 alpha omega">           
                <!-- the links that control animation -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="example link">Example 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="example link">Example 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- end #header --> <div class="main grid_8 alpha omega">
        <div class="content grid_12 alpha">
            <div id="the_content">
                <!-- content is loaded in here via ajax -->
            </div><!-- end the_content -->
        </div><!-- end .content -->

        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="footer">
            Footer stuff
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end .main .grid_8 .alpha .omega -->
</div> <!-- end .container_16 -->
</div> <!-- end scroll -->
```

A brief snippet of CSS:

```
#background_container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#scroll {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The Javascript simply uses jQuery to animate the "left" attribute. I would include it, but there's a lot going on and I don't think it will help bring a solution.

---

Basically, when the background div scrolls from the first position to the last position, the content seems to "scrunch" briefly in Safari.

Video of this behavior: 
[redacted]

In the video, I demo both safari and firefox.  As you can see, in Safari the content scrunches/glitches during the animation.  In Firefox, it does not. Safari is seemingly the only browser that does this. It even works in IE6. :)

The div that appears to "scrunch" seems to be `<div id="header" class="grid_9 suffix_3 alpha omega">` but, sometimes you can see a scroll bar briefly which suggests `<div id="scroll">` may be the root cause.

Is this a Safari rendering issue that's common and can be avoided? Or should I just suck it up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is a "common Safari bug". I think it will be difficult to debug without a test case. Consider making one with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) if you can reproduce it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `-webkit-transform: transform` on the original element so that it gets hardware accelerated on load.

Comment: Perfect! If I could upvote more than once, I would. For others, in case there are questions: I set this on the background div.